# Ruby OpenSSL unable to decrypt

Tags: ruby, openssl, public-key-encryption

I am able to encrypt files, but when I try to decrypt them I am getting "error reading input file".  I am using a public/private keypair to encrypt the passphrase that is used in encrypting the file.  This is so that only the owner of the private key is able to decrypt the file.

My encryption method uses the Ruby OpenSSL module and looks like:

```
file = params[:submission][:report].path
filename = params[:submission][:report].original_filename.gsub(" ", "_")

pubkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read "#{Rails.root.to_s}/key/pubkey.pem"
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key = (0...50).map{ ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join

buf = ""
File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/evidence/#{filename}.enc", "wb") do |outf|
  File.open(file, "rb") do |inf|
    while inf.read(4096, buf)
      outf << cipher.update(buf)
    end
    outf << cipher.final
  end
end

encrypted_key = pubkey.public_encrypt key
File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/evidence/#{filename}_passphrase.bin", 'wb') {|f| f.write(encrypted_key) }
```

Then I am using openssl in a Linux environment to handle the decrypting

```
openssl rsautl -in file_passphrase.bin -out passphrase.txt -inkey privkey.pem -decrypt
openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file.pdf -pass file:passphrase.txt
```

I have also tried using a salt, encrypting/decrypting it the same as the passphrase, and I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a solution, but this works. Instead of the OpenSSL module, I'm just using system commands:

```
file = params[:submission][:report].path
filename = params[:submission][:report].original_filename.gsub(" ", "_")
passphrase = (0...50).map{ ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join
system("openssl enc -a -e -aes-256-cbc -in #{file} -out #{Rails.root.to_s}/evidence/#{filename}.asc -pass pass:#{passphrase}")
system("echo #{passphrase} | openssl rsautl -out #{Rails.root.to_s}/evidence/#{filename}_password.bin -pubin -inkey #{Rails.root.to_s}/key/pubkey.pem -encrypt")
```

Then using the same decryption method as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your encrypted is file base64 encoded. If the lines are longer than 64 characters, then openssl has a problem undoing the base64 encoding and prints *error reading input file*. I'm not sure whether the problem exists with all versions of openssl or not.

Two solutions come to mind:

- base64 decode the file first with another utility and then run the `openssl enc` command without the -a switch
- insert a linefeed after every 64 characters in the encrypted and base64 encoded file (file.enc in your example)